# select dropdown value from grid in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

Please help me select dropdown value from cell in protractor.
BTW its a non angular website

HTML sample:

```
<td data-cellid="RequiredContentTypeId" class="customGridDataCell customGridEditCell" tabindex="-1" xpath="1">
<div data-cellid="RequiredContentTypeId" class="valueContainer">
    <select name="RequiredContentTypeId">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="bd434f35-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">AddtoTest</option>
        <option value="e8b6fd1b-e2f3-e911-aa64-e16c52c442dc">APINV_EPIC06</option>
        <option value="35cfdd50-c47a-e911-aa37-8fe9ba6f0d87">Approve</option>
        <option value="70da50aa-e2a3-e911-aa45-8f65b76e1edb">Basic</option>
        <option value="5af85ad8-5ac0-e911-aa4f-b51108e06dbe">cont</option>
        <option value="1c9b4449-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">Contentgenrat</option>
        <option value="7ea80473-ecdd-e911-aa5b-cc08702b7e65">CTB1</option>
        <option value="fb0b16cb-5fc9-4938-8cdb-b28b0ac3a065">Default</option>
        <option value="5b904ca0-8adb-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">delete</option>
        <option value="9cd4dc48-910b-ea11-aa6c-879f4a104148">GP - US Expense Report</option>
        <option value="7a87e6ae-75b3-e911-aa4b-a33f065bbcc1">INVOICE</option>
        <option value="2860a55d-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">norconnoradd</option>
        <option value="df57386a-90db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">olaa</option>
        <option value="f299ad9c-91db-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">qwerty</option>
        <option value="2fa1a597-63d9-e911-aa59-a96c125b4266">Test1</option>
        <option value="14d4d010-5bc0-e911-aa4f-b51108e06dbe">ton</option>
        <option value="4e0506f8-bd7a-e911-aa37-8fe9ba6f0d87">View</option>
        <option value="15086a03-ebc8-e911-aa54-ce643b10106b">WithNavFieldGroup</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Below is what I tried and it says unable to select locator.
    `await rows[rowNumber].all(by.tagName("td"))
    .get(0)
    .element(by.xpath("//select"))
    .element(by.cssContainingText("option", value))
    .click();`

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: Edited the steps i tried.

Answer (score 1):

Which option are you trying to get?
This can be easily done with one of protractor's methods:

`element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'AddtoTest'));`

Answer (score 0):

select value by text has been mentioned, here is how you do it if you want to select by order number

```
await $('.valueContainer select').click();
await $$('.valueContainer select option[value]').get(0).click();
```